# Removing or truncating git commits past a chosen commit

Tags: git, github, commit

What happened was the repo that was created/pushed to GitHub was done without first removing the old .git folder. So all the commits that were in the dev stack that we used as a boilerplate are now in the history of our git commits, whereas we just wanted to start afresh with 1 commit.

It's too late to simply delete all the work we have and recommit from scratch with a deleted .git folder, so I was wondering if there was an easy way to (permanently) delete, or truncate all commits past a certain point.

The git commit I want the repo to start at (and remove all commits before it), is 13f2e03657173a0cfc8d7ee8a5e6132d03168ef0. There are also a few branches at the moment (master is actually set before the commit mentioned above), and the develop branch is the most up-to-date branch. I'd like to make master start at the commit above.

Ultimately, I'd want no trace of the deleted commits in any of those branches. I've googled this and tried to use a method mentioned but it only ended up causing errors.

Could someone please explain to me one or both ways of dealing with it?

Comment: Could you not just initialize a new Git repo and push it?  This might be easier than what you have in mind.

Comment: Normally you would just force-push to "retract" commits.  They may remain in the repository for a while, but will be invisible (and not show up in clones).